# How to use icon font with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-studio, fonts, icons, android-jetpack-compose

in before xml in TextView we have

holder.binding.iconInfo.text = "&#x${iconValue}"

and set out icon font to it with typeface dose anyone can help same thing but with jetpack compose

Answer (score 0):

The specific syntax you mention that can be used with TextViews is due to the fact that XML is used when defining layouts. That is an [XML numeric character entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) that specifies a character with its unicode value in hexadecimal notation.
So it is not related to TextViews, layouts, fonts or icons.

If you want to do the same with a String in Kotlin and the character value is dynamic, you can do something like this

```kotlin
val text = "${Char(iconValue)}"
```

In Compose a custom font can be defined either as part of your Theme -> Typography and then used as text style or you can define it directly like this

```kotlin
val fontFamily = FontFamily(
    // If you have the font in resources
    Font(R.font.my_font_normal, weight = FontWeight.Normal),
    Font(R.font.my_font_bold, weight = FontWeight.Bold),
    Font(R.font.my_font_italic, weight = FontWeight.Normal, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    // If you are loading the font at runtime from a file
    Font(File(...), weight = FontWeight.Normal),
    // ...
)

// Use with Text composable
Text(text = text, fontFamily = fontFamily)
```